# Adding components dynamically using Action Script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Just started learning Flex. But I am struck up with basic code. I am trying to check how to add components (say button) to the Application container by Action Script. But I am not able to see the buttons in the output. Below is my code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
             creationComplete="init()">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

             import mx.controls.Alert;

             import spark.components.Button;
             import spark.layouts.BasicLayout;

             private function init():void{
                 var bl:BasicLayout = new BasicLayout();
                 var app:Application = new Application();
                 var button1:Button = new Button();
                 var button2:Button = new Button();

                 button1.label ="Button one";
                 button1.x = 100;
                 button2.label = "Two";
                 button2.x = 30;
                 layout = bl;
                 addChild(button1);
                 addChild(button2);


             }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
```

What is the mistake I am doing here?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should tell us what does not work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should even throw a runtime error, because you're not allowed to use `addChild` here.
Since Flex 4 there is a new component set (called `Spark`). When adding visual items to Spark containers, you must use the `addElement` method. And since `s:Application` is a Spark container, you should do it here too. So simply replace `addChild` with `addElement` in your code and it will work.

You might ask: **if I can't use it, why is "addChild" still there?**
Well, the answer is: legacy. All Flex components (i.e. both mx and Spark) inherit from [UIComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html), which implements the `addChild` method for the Flex framework (`addChild` is actually a pure ActionScript method of the [DisplayObjectContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html) class). `addElement` does some additional stuff (I won't get too technical here), which is why you can't use `addChild` anymore. But `addChild` is still there (inherited from `UIComponent`) and will throw an error telling you that you can't use this method.

This is the relevant code from [SkinnableComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableComponent.html):

```
override public function addChild(child:DisplayObject):DisplayObject
{
    throw(new Error(resourceManager.getString("components", "addChildError")));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I checked it in debug mode and clearly said to use addElement instead of addChild. But not sure why it is and came to know the reason from ur answer now.

Comment: It's worth adding that the UIComponent `addChild()` method is not entirely useless at this point. For its children, it is. But you can use UIComponent to add Sprites or its children to a Flex UI, which is not possible using UIComponent children.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familar with BasicLayOut, but I think you can see the button if you keep the code simple:

```
 private function init():void{
            // var bl:BasicLayout = new BasicLayout(); 
            // var app:Application = new Application();
// 1. Create button
             var button1:Button = new Button();
             var button2:Button = new Button();
// 2. customize button
             button1.label ="Button one";
             button1.x = 100;
             button2.label = "Two";
             button2.x = 30;
// 3. add button into the container, 'this' is Applciation
           //  layout = bl;
             addElement(button1); // addChild for Flex3
             addElement(button2);
         }
```

Modify your code and try again, good luck!